# get a list of dependencies that WildFly 8 is loading for a certain sub-deployment at runtime

Tags: jboss, dependencies, wildfly-8

I'm reading this article about Class loading in WildFly:
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Class+Loading+in+WildFly

It talks about implicit dependencies. Is there a way to get a list of dependencies that WildFly/JBoss is loading for a certain sub-deployment at runtime?

Answer (score 2):

You can try with [Tattletale](http://tattletale.jboss.org/), this is an tool that can help you identify module dependencies in your application.

See: [Use Tattletale to find application dependencies.](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Developer+Guide#DeveloperGuide-UseTattletaletofindapplicationdependencies)